# Some voice memos not playing on phone or itunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, audio

I have a bunch of voice memos, all under ten minutes long.  I frequently have trouble syncing them to iTunes--at the moment one in particular won't play on my phone (although it's listed with the correct title and duration) and it's not syncing to the correct playlist.  It appears in iTunes under my phone, but won't play.  Generally, I change all the Voice Memos to the type "Music" and add an artist.  Yesterday it played fine, both on iTunes and on my phone.  I haven't made any changes since then so I have no idea what's different. Using an iPhone 6 and iTunes 12.6

Comment: What happens if you open the voice memo in QuickTime.app on your Mac?

Comment: @oa- I can't import them so I don't know

Comment: Can you send the file to your Mac using the share sheet (AirDrop/iMessage/email)?

Comment: @oa- Nope.  Used to be able to, before they were corrupted (for lack of a better word).  The options come up, but nothing gets sent (or appears in the send screen)

Comment: See my comment in https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/42275/26886